# How do I create a grid of ordered pairs?

Tags: java, grid

My friend's trying to teach me Java and as one of his challenges, he wanted me to create a grid of ordered pairs from 1,1 to 10,10 in a 10 x 10 grid. It should look something like this:

```
1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,6 1,7 1,8 1,9 1,10
2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 2,5 2,6 2,7 2,8 2,9 2,10
...
10,1 10,2 10,3 10,4 10,5 10,6 10,7 10,8 10,9 10,10
```

But I can only seem to print out the ordered pairs in the following format:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
...
10,10
```

How could I go about fixing this issue?

My code so far is:

```
public class project{

 public static void main(String []args){

    for (int x=1;x<=10; x=x+1)
    {
        for (int y=1;y<=10;y=y+1)
        {
            System.out.println(x + "," + y);
        }
    System.out.println("\n");
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.out.print` in your inner loop to have them print on the same line (perhaps add a space at the end).

`Println` does the same as `Print`, but also adds a newline character to it.

A note while we're at it:

`y=y+1` can be shortened to `y++`.

Comment: This was a great answer. I had to format some more with the spaces, but I finally got it. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen's suggestion is spot on. An alternative is, for each "row" of data, build a string with your X,Y information, then spit it only once for each row when the loop is done iterating through the "column". Something like this:

```
for (int x=1;x<=10; x=x+1)
{
    String rowString = "";
    for (int y=1;y<=10;y=y+1)
    {
        rowString += x + "," + y;
    }
    System.out.println(rowString);
}
```